# How do I move this search bar to the top right of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upgCP.png)

How do I move the search bar to the top right corner (html/css) of the screen. Please give me some examples.

Comment: move what? there's nothing in the question to move?

Comment: Did you try Google?

Comment: _i hope i can be good in programming web(javascript and its components) in 6-12 months then go learn app development._ come back once you've read https://stackoverflow.com/help (will take you 6-12 months based on your question)

Comment: Go through w3schools.com. That should help you.

Comment: that is exactly what im using. some youtube long tutorials and already started my own website.i think il finish it in 4 months, like completely. around 10-20 hours per week... in 1 year i should be good to move forward to java and then app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example, you can read more about forms here : 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```html
<div class="search">
  <div id="search1">
    <object align= right>
      <form method="POST" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="type ..">
        <input type="submit" value="search here">
      </form>
    </object>
  </div>
</div>
```